# How to convert data in ratio format(eg 3:2) to decimal in R?

Tags: r

I have a variable called female to male ratio as character.

```
>  head(univ$female_male_ratio)

[1] 33 : 67  37 : 63  42:58:00 45:55:00 46:54:00
```

How do I convert this data type to numeric? for example the first row is 33:67, I want it to be 0.492, which is 33/67

Comment: Hi, for example the first row is 33:67, I want it to be 0.492, which is 33/67

Answer (score 2):

We can split on ":" using `strsplit` and then loop over each list element using `sapply` and get the ratio of first element on second element.

```
sapply(strsplit(ratio, ":"), function(x) as.numeric(x[1])/as.numeric(x[2]))
#[1] 0.4925373 0.5873016 0.7241379 0.8181818 0.8518519
```

**data**

```
ratio <- c("33:67","37:63","42:58:00","45:55:00","46:54:00")
```

Answer (score 2):

An option using `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
as.numeric(sub(":.*", "", gsubfn("([0-9]+):([0-9]+)",
              ~ as.numeric(x)/as.numeric(y), ratio)))
#[1] 0.4925373 0.5873016 0.7241379 0.8181818 0.8518519
```

#### data

```
ratio <- c("33:67","37:63","42:58:00","45:55:00","46:54:00")
```